# Linq PredicateBuilder - Multiple ORs

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use the PredicateBuilder, as described here - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

The following code

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<StreetDTO>();

        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Locality.Contains(criteria.Locality));
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Name.Contains(criteria.Name));
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Town.Contains(criteria.Town));

        List<StreetDTO> streetData = StreetData.Instance();

        var streetList = from street in streetData.Where(predicate)
                         select street;
```

as far as I see this *should* work, according to the example

```
var newKids  = Product.ContainsInDescription ("BlackBerry", "iPhone");

var classics = Product.ContainsInDescription ("Nokia", "Ericsson")
                      .And (Product.IsSelling());
var query =
  from p in Data.Products.Where (newKids.Or (classics))
  select p;
```

but all I get is

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I'm trying to gain some understanding in LINQ 'on-the-job', so apologies if this is a simple question.

Comment: thanks for let me know about PredicateBuilder!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah; your list is using `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods (rather than `IQueryable<T>`) - try:

```
var streetList = from street in streetData.AsQueryable().Where(predicate)
                 select street;
```

Comment: That's the one - thanks!  I'll need to get myself a decent Linq book, I don't think it's something you can learn on the hoof...

Comment: LINQ in Action, or the later chapters of C# in Depth are pretty good.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the indications about LINQ in Action. =)

Answer (score 11):

Try compiling your predicate:

```
var streetList = from street in streetData.Where(predicate.Compile())
                 select street;
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked, although I marked Marc as the answer as I found another answer that matched his elsewhere.  I'm not sure which way is preferred?

Comment: @Duncan, I'm not sure witch is the preferred way either :( This has to do with how linq works it's magic *inside*. I don't believe that you'll hit any major problems in terms of performance if you use one or the other.