# Add WHERE clauses to SQL dynamically / programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

How can I add search condition to SQL Stored Procedure programmatically?
In my application(C#) I'm using stored procedure (SQL Server 2008R2)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC001]
@userID varchar(20),
@password varchar(20)
AS
SELECT * FROM tUsers WHERE RTRIM(Name) = @userID AND RTRIM(Password) = @password
```

I want to extend this query by more conditions, and now I don't know how many conditions will use this query due program execution.. 2, 3, 6 OR 20. I want to add these conditions programmatically like:

```
SELECT * FROM tUsers WHERE RTRIM(Name) = @userID AND RTRIM(Password) = @password
AND Field2 = '1' AND Field3 = '0' OR Field4 <> '8' AND Field5 < '100' ....
```

Is it possible to sent conditions to stored procedure dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977021/can-a-stored-procedure-have-dynamic-parameters-to-be-used-in-an-in-clause

Comment: @phadaphunk maybe it could be a possible duplicate, but it would be more productive if you point the questioner to a [possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure/3415629#3415629), that's the spirit of this site, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit - Preference for LINQ based ORM's, if possible**

If you don't need to do this in ADO, a better solution is to use an ORM which will ultimately build parameterized ad-hoc sql. This is the best of both worlds - you get the flexibility of a dynamic query, with no redundant filters to upset the optimizer, the query plan itself is cacheable, and you are safe from nasties like injection attacks. And a Linq-based ORM query makes for easy reading:

```cs
 // Build up a non-materialized IQueryable<>
 var usersQuery = db.Users;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
 {
       usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(u => u.Name == userId);
 }
 // Of course, you wouldn't dream of storing passwords in cleartext.
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherField))
 {
       usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(u => u.AnotherColumn == anotherField);
 }
 ...
 // Materialize (and execute) the query
 var filteredUsers = usersQuery.ToList();
```

For complex queries, you may want to look at [PredicateBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877034)

**ADO / manual query building**

You can use `sp_executesql` to build up SQL dynamically as per below. Provided that you parameterize the variables you should be safe from issues like SQL injection and escaping quotes etc will be handled for you.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC001]
    @userID varchar(20),
    @pwdHash varchar(20),
    @optionalParam1 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL -- Other optional parameters
AS        
    BEGIN        
        SET NOCOUNT ON        

        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)        

        -- Mandatory / Static part of the Query here. 
        -- Cleartext passwords are verboten, and RTRIM is redundant in filters
        SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM tUsers WHERE Name = @userID AND PwdHash = @pwdHash'

        IF @OptionalParam1 IS NOT NULL        
            BEGIN        
                SET @SQL = @SQL + N' AND AnotherField = @OptionalParam1'    
            END        

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,        
            N'@userID varchar(20),
            @pwdHash varchar(20),
            @optionalParam1 NVARCHAR(50)'
            ,@userID = @userID
            ,@pwdHash = @pwdHash
            ,@optionalParam1 = @optionalParam1
    END
```

**Re, why is `WHERE (@x IS NULL OR @x = Column)` a bad idea?**

(From my comment below)

Although the 'optional parameter' pattern works well as a 'swiss army knife' for querying a multitude of permutations of optional filters when used on small tables, unfortunately, for large tables, this results in a single query plan for all permutations of filters for the query, which can result in poor query performance with certain permutations of optional parameters due to the [parameter sniffing problem](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/parameter-sniffing/). If possible, you should eliminate redundant filters entirely.

**Re: Why is applying functions in predicates a bad idea**

e.g.

```
WHERE SomeFunction(Column) = @someParameter
```

Use of functions in predicates frequently disqualifies the use of indexes by the RDBMS (["non-sargable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)).

In this instance, `RTRIM` is unnecessary as Sql server [ignores](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/kb/316626) trailing spaces [during comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166159/sql-where-clause-matching-values-with-trailing-spaces).

Answer (score 21):

You can do this in sql only, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tUsers 
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (@userID IS NULL OR RTRIM(Name) = @userID )
  AND (@password IS NULL OR RTRIM(Password) = @password)
  AND (@field2 IS NULL OR Field2 = @field2)
....
```

If any parameter passed to the stored procedure with a `NULL` value then the whole condition will be ignored.

**Note that**: I added `WHERE 1 = 1` in order to make the query work in case no parameter passed to the query and in this case alll the result set will be returned, since `1 = 1` is always true.

Comment: +1 This works well for small tables, but note for large tables, this results in a single query plan for all permutations of filters for the query, which can result in poor query performance with certain permutations of optional parameters. If possible, you should eliminate redundant filters entirely.

Comment: Do you think that @StuartLC is correct on his argument. Is dynamic sql is the better option here?

Comment: The better solution is to use an ORM which will ultimately build **parameterized** ad-hoc sql. This is the best of both worlds - you get the flexibility of a dynamic query, with no redundant filters to upset the optimizer, the query plan itself is cacheable, and you are safe from nasties like injection attacks. And a Linq-based ORM query makes for easy reading.

Comment: It slows the query down in big tables. It works well in small tables.

Comment: no need for `RTRIM` as in those two with the predicate `OR RTRIM(Password) = @password` perhaps

Comment: [There is no need for "1=1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure/3415629#3415629)

Answer (score 2):

you could have your procedure as string, and send a string with the conditions, concatenate and exec.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC001] @userID varchar(20), @password varchar(20), @WhereToAdd varchar(MAX) AS 

exec ('SELECT * FROM tUsers WHERE RTRIM(Name) = @userID AND RTRIM(Password) = @password AND ' + @WhereToAdd)
```