# Using Join based on condition

Tags: sql, join

Can anyone please explain me how can we use join on the basis of condition. 
Lets say i am filtering data on the basis of a condition now my concern is if a particular BIT type parameters value is 1 then the data set include one more join else return same as earlier.
Here is three tables A,B,C 
now i want to make a proc which has the @bool bit parameter

```
if @bool=0
then  
select A.* from A 
inner join B on B.id=A.id
and if @bool=1 
then 
select A.* from A
INNER JOIN B on B.id=A.id
inner join C on C.id=A.id
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do you mean *else if* instead of *and if*  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work (certainly in a SPROC in MS SQL Server anyway) with minor mods.

```
if @bool=0 then  
   select A.* from A 
   inner join B on B.id=A.id
else if @bool=1 then -- Or just else if @boll is limited to [0,1]
   select A.* from A
   INNER JOIN B on B.id=A.id
   inner join C on C.id=A.id
```

However, the caveat is that SQL parameter sniffing will cache a plan for the first path it goes down, which won't necessarily be optimal for other paths through your code.

Also, if you do take this 'multiple alternative query' approach to your procs, it is generally a good idea to ensure that the column names and types returned are identitical in all cases (Your query is fine because it is A.*).

**Edit**
Assuming that you are using SQL Server, an alternative is to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = N'select A.* from A 
             inner join B on B.id=A.id'

IF @bool = 1
    SET @sql = @sql + N' inner join C on C.id=A.id'

sp_executesql @sql
```

If you need to add filters etc, have a look at this post: [Add WHERE clauses to SQL dynamically / programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329823/add-where-clauses-to-sql-dynamically-programmatically)

Comment: I don't want to use these two conditions. Instead of two diffrent conditon cann't we do this in single condition like select A.* from A inner join B on B.id=A.id case when @bool=1 then inner join C on c.id    like this i know its wrong way but want similar logic. ThankYou

Comment: @champ - updated with dynamic sql option. I've assumed sql server from your earlier post.

Comment: Hey nonnb Thank you so much i think dynamic sql is better option. Thnx again

Comment: @champ - your welcome! One thing to remember when using dynamic sql is to ensure any variables etc are parameterized (where myfield=@value1 etc). Else you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You do it using a union:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A 
    INNER JOIN B on B.id=A.id 
WHERE bool = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT A.* 
FROM A 
    INNER JOIN B on B.id=A.id 
    INNER JOIN C on C.id=A.id 
WHERE bool = 1
```

I'm assuming that `bool` is stored in table `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.* from A
inner join B on B.id = A.id
left outer join C on C.id = A.id and @bool = 1
where (@bool = 1 and C.id is not null) or @bool = 0
```

The `@bool = 1` "activates" the left outer join, so to speak, and turns it, in effect, into an inner join by applying it in the `WHERE` clause, too. If `@bool = 0` then the left outer join returns nothing from C and removes the `WHERE` restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B on B.id=A.id
INNER JOIN C on C.id=A.id and @bool=1
```