# Need help on escaping characters for dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The query should return a result where table = 'alrt'
but it have an error on escaping the quotation

```
declare @dbname nvarchar(max)  
declare @query nvarchar(max)  
set @dbname = 'alrt'  
set @query ='SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,convert(nvarchar(max),last_user_seek),last_user_scan,last_user_lookup,last_system_update FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats WHERE database_id = DB_ID ('+'''Frontoffrob'''+') AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('+@dbname+')'
exec (@query)
```

Error Result

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'alrt'.
```

.
.
.
The following query is working
`SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS DatabaseName,convert(nvarchar(max),last_user_scan)as SCAN FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats WHERE database_id = DB_ID ('Frontoffrob') AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID ('ALRT')`

Output:

> +--DatabaseName--+----Last_user_SCAN----+
>       |__ ALRT ***_*__*_*__*_*_**|_ Aug 30 2013  1:47PM_|

Comment: I would recommend that instead you [parameterize the variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329823/add-where-clauses-to-sql-dynamically-programmatically). This will avoid the escaping issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WHERE` clause use this:

```
'SELECT ... AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('''+@dbname+''')'
```

Actually, your query should look like this:

```
set @query =
'SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS DatabaseName, 
    last_user_update,
    convert(nvarchar(max),last_user_seek),
    last_user_scan,
    last_user_lookup,
    last_system_update 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
WHERE database_id = DB_ID (''Frontoffrob'') 
AND 
OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(''' + @dbname+''')'
```