# MSSQL 2008: Problems with the 'Case' - statement

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, syntax-error, case

I'm having some troubles finding a solution to my SQL-Problem. I've tried google but so far my search didn't give me any statisfactory results.

I have an SSRS report with two parameters:

```
 @SupplierId NVARCHAR (May contain NULL)
 @EmployeeId NVARCHAR (May contain NULL)
```

My original query retrieved all the employees who came in service during the last year:

```
SELECT Name, Surname from dbo.Employee Where Employee.DateInService > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Right now i want to add those parameters to the query using the following logic.

**Remark this is pseudo SQL:**

```
SELECT
...
FROM ...
WHERE Employee.DateInService > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AND
IF (LEN(RTRIM(@SupplierId)) = 0 Or @SupplierID IS NULL ) THEN
      dbo.Employee.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
Else
      dbo.Employee.SupplierId = @SupplierId
```

My search sofar led me to the `Case` statement. I made a query which contains an syntax error (obviously). My base query:

```
SELECT
...
FROM ...
WHERE Employee.DateInService > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AND
CASE WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(@SupplierId)) = 0) THEN
      dbo.Employee.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
Else
      dbo.Employee.SupplierId = @SupplierId
```

**Error:** Syntax error near '='.

**Question 1:** Why does he give an error near the '='?

**Question 2:** How do i correctly implement the following:

```
CASE WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(@SupplierId)) = 0 "Or @SupplierId is null" ) THEN
```

Instead of

```
CASE WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(@SupplierId)) = 0) Then dbo.Employee.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
     WHEN (@SupplierId IS NULL) Then dbo.Employee.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
     ELSE dbo.Employee.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId END
```

**Note:** if i've missed a post during my google searches, please don't hesitate to point it out.

Thanks for your help

Comment: nvarchar for IDs? Really?

Comment: thats SAP for you my friend (not my call). Nor will it ever be. EmployeeIds here look like '00004567', ' 00123458' ,...

Comment: Now I remember why I don't work with SAP!! :)

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*. It produces a *value*. It's not a control flow *statement*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Still, the construction would work if `CASE` was allowed to result in boolean expressions.

Comment: @ypercube - We're still waiting for SQL Server to expose a boolean data type, so I guess that day's a long way off yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the actual query predicate like that with `CASE` - there are 2 distinct queries depending on the value of `@SupplierId`. You can conditionally apply the filter as follows (I've assumed the `@SupplierId` = null flow is the same as the whitespace branch:

```
SELECT
...
FROM ...
WHERE Employee.DateInService > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) 
  AND
  (
    (dbo.Employee.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId 
      AND (LEN(RTRIM(@SupplierId)) = 0 OR @SupplierId IS NULL))
    OR
    (dbo.Employee.SupplierId = @SupplierId AND LEN(RTRIM(@SupplierId)) > 0)
  )
```

Although this can be prone to query plan sniffing related performance issues, in which case you might need to consider an alternative approach, e.g. using [parameterized dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11330095/314291) to build up and execute the sql, as there are 2 distinct process flows through the query.

**Edit**

As per Ypercube's comment above, in order to provide the boolean result needed for the predicate, if you can find a <del>hack</del> workaround is to find a way to project a COMMON scalar from each of the `CASE` .. `WHEN` row and then do a comparison of the scalar. In the example below, projecting a yes / no flag.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee 
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(@SupplierId)) = 0 OR @SupplierId IS NULL) 
          THEN CASE WHEN dbo.Employee.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ELSE CASE WHEN dbo.Employee.SupplierId = @SupplierId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    END = 1;
```

But the big problem with this approach is performance - the above will require a full scan to determine the results.

Comment: Wil try it in an hour or so. I'll keep you posted. Thanks for the effort already made though! :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! thnx mate!